# nuxt does not start on Arch

Tags: nuxt.js

I can not start my nuxt development enviroment for 2 days. Before that I had no problem. If I go back to a previous version of the same app, it is also not starting.

```sh
npm run dev

> KrisnaNet@1.0.0 dev
> nuxt


 ERROR  (node:3576) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /home/rrd/public_html/krisnaNet/node_modules/@nuxt/components/package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.4                      │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      static               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                                  16:00:33
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                                     16:00:33
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md                                                                  16:00:33
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                16:00:33
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                               16:00:33

● Client █████████████████████████ building (43%) 283/293 modules 10 active
 node_modules/setimmediate/setImmediate.js

● Server █████████████████████████ building (23%) 113/121 modules 8 active
 ...ostcss-loader › sass-loader › sass-resources-loader › vue-loader › layouts/default.vue

node: ../src/coroutine.cc:134: void* find_thread_id_key(void*): Assertion `thread_id_key != 0x7777' failed.
fish: Job 1, 'npm run dev' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is totally unrelated to arch if you did not upgraded anything. Do you have some git changes ? Maybe just typo'ed in your editor while it had your mouse focus ? What is the content of `coroutine.cc` ?

Comment: This is part of the fiber package. The fle is here https://controlc.com/27cf1c1b I reinstalled all packages, it is not a typo I guess.

Comment: I am having the same issue in Gitlab CI deployment. On my local machine it works just fine. Did you find a solution already?

Comment: it is caused by node 16 and fibers incompatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing `fibers` (that is responsible for this error) from the dependencies. This might affect the build performance a little bit but everything works for me now.

Comment: it is caused by node 16 and fibers incompatibility